# Best use of the WITH ROLLUP in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following query in MySQL;

```
SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT
     DATE( logdate )                     as Date
        ,WEEK( logdate,0 )               as Week
        ,DATE_FORMAT(logdate, '%M')      as Month
        ,CONVERT(netID,UNSIGNED INTEGER) as netID
        ,COUNT(callsign)                 as Logins
        ,COUNT( IF(creds <> '',1,NULL))  as creds
        ,COUNT( IF(comments LIKE '%first log in%',1,NULL) ) as newb
        ,SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(timeonduty))    as TOD
        ,activity
     FROM NetLog
    WHERE netID <> 0 
          AND netcall = 'W0KCN' 
          AND logdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH 
          AND activity NOT LIKE '%TEST%'
  GROUP BY netID WITH ROLLUP) AS t
ORDER BY netID DESC
```

It produces the following;

[image]

Please notice the rollup row at the bottom.  I would like to add a rollup by Week.Each appearing after the last Week row.

The problem(s) I’ve run into include;

1)  Everytime I rerun the query the rollup line and other rows as well, move. They literally appear on different row numbers than where they belong. The values are correct but the row is wrong. For example the rollup at the bottom might appear two rows up from its current position, or four, or one.

2)  I’d like to be able to sort by ASC or DESC and still have the rollup rows appear in the correct places, but after days (yes days) of trial and error  I still can’t figure out how to do that.

Comment: Which version of MySQL? Also, please take a look at the docs, there are some important remarks and things to consider: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.5.47-0+deb8u1 - (Debian)
Protocol version: 10
User: keith@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: This means, the order direction is still allowed in the GROUP BY clause. Worth a try. An FYI, NULL is treated as larger than any value when it comes to ORDER BY, this is why these records are listed at the end. You may want to add all the columns to either GROUP BY or use aggregation functions to get rid of the extra info listed in the superaggregated records. Also, you can try to order by the minus value using ASC (prevents index usage). Anyways, this kind of ordering should/can be done in the client app.

Comment: I'm going to give this one to you because the problem I had was with the DESC. Once I removed that it worked. If I need to re-sort I'll do it as you suggest.